# How can I get node-sass watch and live reload to work from a single NPM script?

Tags: node.js, npm, livereload, node-sass

Taking the following scripts section from a `package.json`:

```
"scripts":{
    "sass:watch": "npm run sass -- -w ./src/public/stylesheets -r --source-map true",
    "livereload": "live-reload --port 9091 ./src/**/*",
    "dev:watch" : "npm run sass:watch; npm run livereload"
}
```

How can I successfully get both the **`sass:watch`** and **`livereload`** tasks to run, without blocking each other, from the **`dev:watch`** task?

Currently, when I run **`npm run dev:watch`** **`sass:watch`** blocks **`livereload`**.

If I reorder them, the same problem occurs.

Comment: btw, which `live-reload` is it? There is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) one that seems not have a npm `run`. Or am I missing something..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [parallelshell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell).

[Here's how I'm doing it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34816925/3869481)

With live-server it'll look like:

```
"serve": "live-server",
"start": "parallelshell \"npm run scss && npm run scss -- -w\" \"npm run serve\""
```

Comment: I believe it is better to use `concurrently` or `npm-run-all` as those are updated more frequently, and the community is wider. `parallelshell` was updated three years ago.

Answer (score 15):

Use a single ampersand:

`"dev:watch" : "npm run sass:watch & npm run livereload"`

`&&` runs tasks in serial; `&` in parallel.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I love answers like this.  Very simple, and no need for another dependency.

Comment: Does this work cross-platform or Linux and OSX based only? In other words, is it windows-friendly?

Comment: It only works in a `UNIX-like` environment, because of the & ampersand sign. If you wish to run it on Windows you would probably better go with `"dev:watch": "concurrently  \" npm run sass:watch \" \" npm run livereload  \" "` like described down below, or `"dev": "npm-run-all --parallel sass:watch livereload"` [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all). I have tested `WSL2`, it starts the live-server and the sass compiler, but it does not reload the page. And even git bash did not work for me (I may miss something, but I tried, and it just gets stuck like in cmd console)

Answer (score 8):

you could try the **concurrently** package for npm

> npm install concurrently --save-dev

then use it to run  both of your script:

```
"dev:watch": "concurrently  \" npm run sass:watch \" \" npm run livereload  \" ",
```

you can find info about the package here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use for small npm script based projects: I simply run `npm start` and start working ;)

- `concurrently` launches the corresponding tasks in parallel
- `node-sass` is responsible for the sass->css generation
- it needs to reran the sass task with the `--watch` option for monitoring of 
  `sass` related changes
- and finally `lite-server` starts the server with the build-in live-reload support. By default, it watches for changes for the following file extensions: `html,htm,css,js`, but everything can be easily adjusted with the configuration files `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js`.

Relevant parts of the `package.json`:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --names \"SASS,WATCH,SERVE\" -c \"bgBlue.bold,bgMagenta.bold,bgGreen.bold\" \"npm run sass\" \"npm run sass:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "serve": "lite-server",
    "sass": "node-sass style.sass --output ./ --indent-width 4 --output-style expanded --indent-type space --source-map true",
    "sass:watch": "npm run sass -- --watch"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3"
  }
```

This works well for me on Windows 10 and as well as on the GNU/Linux based distros like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't, in a useful way.

You could push one task to the background by appending `&` to its command line, but that would keep the task running even when you `^C` to stop the running NPM task.

Alternatively, you can call `npm run ...` twice and bg one:

```
$ npm run sass:watch &
$ npm run livereload
```

But that's pretty messy too IMO.

If you want this sort of thing, consider using [`gulp`](http://gulpjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Grunt Concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent)

> This task is also useful if you need to run multiple blocking tasks like nodemon and watch at once.