# How to include a folder with scss files to an asp.net project or how to use it and is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, sass

I tried include them as css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/coffee/card.coffee"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/scss/card.scss"/>
```

Comment: You need to compile them to css files. By default available in MVC and Core. For webforms see https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use npm, see [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), it is an npm package that compiles your sass into css. And then you'll be able to link your compiled css file in your html.

It also allows you to setup a watcher, which will recompile your styles when you make a change. More information on how to do this using npm scripts can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797140/using-node-sass-watch-option-with-npm-run-script).