# How do I get SASS with auto-refresh?

Tags: web, npm, sass, watch

When entering the command
`npm install sass --watch ...`

I get back,

**npm ERR! enoent This is realated to npm not being able to find a file.**

Though, the file is there and everything is spelled correctly.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey John take a look at [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350417/how-can-i-get-node-sass-watch-and-live-reload-to-work-from-a-single-npm-script). Basically there are different solutions:

**Single Ampersand solution**

Adding to your `package.json` the following:

```
"dev:watch" : "npm run sass:watch & npm run livereload"
```

**Parallelshell solution**

Using [Parallelshell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell) and adding to your `package.json` the following:

```
"serve": "live-server",
"start": "parallelshell \"npm run scss && npm run scss -- -w\" \"npm run serve\""
```

**Concurrently solution**

Using [Concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). Install it `npm install concurrently --save-dev` and add the script:

```
"dev:watch": "concurrently  \" npm run sass:watch \" \" npm run livereload  \" "
```